# how to import packages properly in an __init__.py files?

Tags: python, python-import

I am having issues creating a basic library. This is my first time attempting this so a complete noob here. I am running a simple example case as shown below.

```
packagetest
     |-> _init_.py
     |-> func
         |-> _init_.py
         |-> sin.py
         |-> cos.py
```

And, a main file `package_test.py`

This library and the main file exists in the same directory.

Inside the `fucn` `__inti__.py`, I have `import numpy as np`. I do not import numpy in  `sin.py` and `cos.py`.

When I access the functions within the sin.py and cos.py modules (which uses numpy), I write `from packagetest.func.sin import foo`. Imports without an error; however, when I use  `foo`, why do I get an error saying 'np' isn't defined. From reading the Modules documentation and other previous posts, my understanding is that `__init__.py` is implicty run when I import any  module in the directory. And, it does that! I added a print statement in func's `__init__` file. When I import, say, `sin.py` using the statement aforementioned, the print statement gets printed! so, the numpy is being imported --I think. How come the `foo` within the sin/cos modules don't "see" it? Isn't the purpose of the `__init__` to run a common code that can be used/seen by all the module in the same directory? I'm clearly missing a dot here to connect my current understanding of `__init__.py` files.

Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Try adding both __init__.py files code and sin.py code and show what line works and what does not

Comment: If `sin.py` and `cos.py` need numpy, then you have to import it there.  Imports are not automatically inherited.  If the package has already been imported, there is no additional cost to importing it again.

Comment: "however, when I use foo, why do I get an error saying 'np' isn't defined." Of course, because you never defined `np`, e.g. by doing `import numpy as np` in `sin.py` and `cos.py`. You still have to do that.

Comment: "so, the numpy is being imported" yes. But no name `np` is available in those other modules. when you `import numpy` it loads the module (or retreives it from `sys.modules` if it's already been loaded) then adds it to the current modules namespace. That doesn't make it available in other namespaces (that would be bad! defeating the whole purpose of namespaces).

Comment: " Isn't the purpose of the `__init__` to run a common code that can be used/seen by all the module in the same directory?" no, no it isn't. `__init__.py` is just the file that will provide the source code for `package.func`

Comment: @TimRoberts. I didn't know imports weren't inherited from the ```__init__```. Yea, I will just add them to the individual module. Thanks!

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I clearly need to do more due diligence when it comes to understanding ```__init__.py```. My thinking was "When I import the ```sin/cos.py``` the imports in the  ```__init__.py``` will be brought into the main file namespace. So, when the code is imported from the packages, the ```np```  is already defined." I was wrong. My question now is why bother writing any import code in the ```__init__.py```, if it needs to imported in each module. Or, are we not supposed to do that in the first place? Thanks!

Comment: @Sushi frequently, `__init__.py` is empty. Sometimes, you might put some initialization logic there. Sometimes, you have a bunch of submodules in the package, say there is a package `packagetest.foo`,  which are "internal", say `packagetest.foo.submodle`, and you expose those to the main package level by doing `from .submodule import Foo` etc so then you can just do `import package.foo` and use `package.foo.Foo` instead of having to do `import package.foo.submodule` then `package.foo.submodule.Foo`

Comment: But yeah, it sounds like you had the wrong idea. The whole point of namespaces is that we do not just implicitly merge them. That is why `from something import *` is so heavily discouraged.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thank you so much for clearing that up! Appreciate it.

Comment: So, this happens in most big packages. consider `panda`, if you `import pandas` you will have access to `pandas.DataFrame`, but if you check `pandas.DataFrame.__module__` you'll see that it is defined in `'pandas.core.frame'`. So `pandas` defines the public API, reach deeper at your own peril